# How to get motherboard vendor/info on OS X programatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, iokit

How to get motherboard vendor/info on OS X programatically?
I didn't find any info in system_profiler. Is it possible to gather such info using obj C/C?

Answer (score 0):

By "motherboard model" I assume you mean the Mac model name? There are a number of ways to get it, but [this has been answered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377702/getting-mac-model-number-on-cocoa).

All Macs are made by Apple, so that's your vendor.

If you're thinking of Hackintoshes, I suspect you'll find it difficult to get much information on the real underlying hardware. As I understand it, Hackintosh boot loaders simulate firmware in such a way that the system pretends to be genuine Apple hardware, so that's what the OS sees.

You can use the IORegistryExplorer tool (or the IOJones clone) to explore the information the kernel has on the hardware and drivers.