# How can I get the model number of macbook programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to get the Model number like `MGX72xx/A` , `MGX82xx/A` and `MGX92xx/A`.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201300[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQiQ1.png) Listed all the model number. but don't know how can I get programmatically?

[image]

Comment: On Linux, we might use `dmidecode` to read strings like this from the firmware. [Apparently](http://forge.fusioninventory.org/projects/fusioninventory-agent/wiki/Get_Data_For_The_TestSuite), "On Mac OS X,`dmidecode` is not mandatory, because we use the [`system_profiler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html) command." Note that this is probably going to require root privileges (or whatever you Mac people call it).

Comment: You can get the model name by using `sysctlbyname`, as noted in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7377952/28804. However, that will give you a string like "MacBookPro11,1", not a more specific model number.

Comment: @ParagBafna I want to get the different result don't mark as  duplicate. you should compare the question properly

Comment: @SidShah If its present in mac hardware report than you can fetch info using sysctl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the model number.

You can get the [model identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7377952/1445366), [serial number](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn1103/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10002943-CH1-TNTAG3), or [full marketing name](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98089/30370) though.

Comment: hummmm.. looks like its not possible.. Ok thanks for the support..!!1